# How to read an XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Assume I have an XML file as below:

```
<TEST>
 <RESULT>
    <REPORT_CREATION_TIME> 15:22:34 </REPORT_CREATION_TIME>
    <TEST_START_TIME> 15:22:34 </TEST_START_TIME>
    <TEST_END_TIME> 15:22:54 </TEST_END_TIME>
    <ERRORS_FOUND> 0 </ERRORS_FOUND>
 </RESULT>
</TEST>
```

and I want to print the following into the console:

```
REPORT_CREATION_TIME = 15:22:34 // node name and value
TEST_START_TIME = 15:22:34
TEST_END_TIME = 15:22:54
ERRORS_FOUND = 0
```

I don't want to use LINQ statements. How to do this?

I'm currently with

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\TEST.xml");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("TEST/RESULT");
```

Comment: [Click](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548).

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("TEST/RESULT");
foreach(XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", child.Name, child.Value.Trim());
}
```

Like this?

Comment: Florian you have very quick hands! B-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
         XmlNodeList oList = oDoc.SelectNodes("TEST/RESULT");
            foreach (XmlNode oNode in oList)
            {
                 string name = oNode.Name;
                 string Value = oNode.Value;
//Do whatever you want
            }
```